# c# NormalDistribution implementation

Tags: c#, excel, normal-distribution

I need the C# implementation(source code) of a `NormalDistribution` function in `System.Web.DataVisualization.dll`, I tried source using the already available functions from github to calculate NORM.S.DIST but they are not accurate and not matching with excel values.

Below is the code I used and it gives me 1.2664557440189636E-43 (almost zero) for an input of 13.803404798240017. On the other hand excel and the `NormalDistribution` function in `DataVisualization` retruns 1 as the result.

```
public static double NS(double zValue)
{
    const double b1 = 0.319381530;
    const double b2 = -0.356563782;
    const double b3 = 1.781477937;
    const double b4 = -1.821255978;
    const double b5 = 1.330274429;
    const double p = 0.2316419;
    const double c = 0.39894228;

    if (zValue >= 0.0)
    {
        double t = 1.0 / (1.0 + p * zValue);
        return (1.0 - c * Math.Exp(-zValue * zValue / 2.0) * t * (t * (t * (t * (t * b5 + b4) + b3) + b2) + b1));
     }
     else
     {
         double t = 1.0 / (1.0 - p * zValue);
         return (c * Math.Exp(-zValue * zValue / 2.0) * t * (t * (t * (t * (t * b5 + b4) + b3) + b2) + b1));
      }
}
```

I tried `ILSpy` to see the code in `DataVisualization.dll` but no luck, please suggest how to we get that source code(if possible), I thought MS has open sourced their .Net code base but it's not true for all assemblies. or is there any better way to calculate NORM.S.DIST with good accuracy?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference you mention between the two calculations could be due to the difference between the density distribution and cumulative distribution. For a z value of 13.80, the density function would be virtually 0 while the cumulative distribution would be virtually 1.
The excel function NORMAL.S.DISTR(z,cumulative) allows to specify this difference as an argument.
I would suggest looking at both implementations to make sure they are both either cumulative or density.
Regarding alternative libraries I would recommend the NuGet package: "MathNet.Numerics"
This package contains implementations of several statistical distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have checked the legal aspect of doing so, and if there is no restriction from Ms (in regard to the type of license for example), then you can use [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/decompiler/2016.1/dotPeek_Introduction.html) to decompile any assembly into C#

Comment: I found an open source project for all Mathematical formulas in c#, I think I can fork the code which I need from it.